# Diamond made out of pararel lines in Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I've got to make a diamond, it has to have the exact same amount of lines the user desires. I'm stuck, I've been thinking for a long time, but didn't get anywhere. My diamond needs to be like in the picture:

[image: Diamond with desired number of lines]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you've accepted your own solution, it's painful to watch it draw.  You've biased your thinking in always working from left to right and breaking the problem into two separate halves.  Let's draw a single shape that solves the problem while thinking bidirectionally:

```
import turtle

lines = int(raw_input('How many lines do you wish your diamond to have? (Odd number only): '))

half = lines // 2
canvas = max(200, lines + 1)
shrinkage = canvas / float(lines)

clyde = turtle.Turtle()
clyde.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

clyde.forward(canvas)
clyde.penup()
clyde.left(90)
clyde.forward(shrinkage)
clyde.left(90)

for i in range(1, half + 1):

    clyde.forward(shrinkage)

    for j in range(2):
        clyde.pendown()
        clyde.forward(canvas - i * shrinkage * 2)  # visible horizontal lines
        clyde.penup()
        clyde.left(90)
        clyde.forward(((i * 2) + j) * shrinkage)  # invisible vertical lines
        clyde.left(90)

clyde.hideturtle()

turtle.mainloop()
```

In this example, I'm intentionally leaving out your input error checking as well as your coercion of the end points to a single pixel.  You can add those back later:

[image]

Watch how your solution draws then watch this one.  Notice that there are fewer wasted motions.  It draws both left to right and right to left.  It draws the pattern as a series of rectangles that are getting narrower and taller:

[image]

but leaving key lines invisible.  If you follow it with your mouse, you can see it's actually a spriral.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution. I'm relatively new to programming, and though mecanic, that was the only way I figured out from writing the code line by line and then defining functions and adding loops. Also, I selected my own solution because I'm also new to StackOverflow and didn't expect anyone else to give an answer. Your solution looks good, and I'll select it as correct as soon as I try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
nl = 5

for line in range(nl):
    if line < nl/2:      
        spc = (int(nl/2-line))*' '
        dsh = (line*2+1)*'_'
        print(spc, dsh)
    else:
        spc = (int(line-nl/2+1))*' '
        dsh = ((nl-line)*2-1)*'_'
        print(spc, dsh)
```

it will produce:

```
   _
  ___
 _____
  ___
   _
```

Answer (score 0):

If printing out as text, try messing around with for loops, the '_' character, and spaces

EDIT:
Here's some pseudocode,

```
For i in range(totalLines/2):
   For j in range(totalLines/2 - i):
       Print(" ")
   For j in range(i):
       Print("_")

For i in range(totalLines/2):
   For j in range(totalLines/2 - i):
       Print("_")
   For j in range(i):
       Print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The title says it needs to be done in Python Turtle. But oh well. I figured out a code that makes what I asked for, the only problem is there is a gap between the top and the bottom halves.
Here's my code:

```
import turtle

clyde = turtle.Turtle()
P.S.: I speak spanish, but you should understand my code easily.

while True:
    try:
        lineas = int(raw_input('Cuantas lineas quieres que tenga tu rombo?(Numero Impar): '))
        assert lineas > 2 and lineas < 646 and lineas % 2 != 0
        break
    except AssertionError:
        if lineas > 646 or lineas < 2:
            print "El numero de lineas debe ser entre de 3 a 645."
            print
        else:
            print 'El numero deber ser un impar positivo.'
            print
    except:
        print 'Ingresa un numero valido'
        print

if lineas <= 21:
    clyde.speed(8)
elif lineas <= 41:
    clyde.speed(5)
else:
    clyde.speed(0)

canvas = 200

if lineas > canvas:
    canvas = lineas + 1

def trasPunta(punta):
    clyde.pu()
    clyde.goto(0, punta)
    clyde.pd()
    clyde.fd(1)
    clyde.pu()
    clyde.back(1)
def drawLine(inc):
    clyde.pd()
    clyde.fd(inc * (canvas / float(lineas)))
    clyde.pu()
    clyde.bk(inc * (canvas / float(lineas)))

trasPunta(canvas / 2.0)
a = 2
for i in range(lineas / 2):

    clyde.right(90)
    clyde.fd(canvas / float(lineas))
    clyde.right(90)
    clyde.fd(canvas / float(lineas))
    clyde.right(180)

    drawLine(a)
    a += 2

trasPunta((-canvas / 2.0) + (canvas / float(lineas)))
b = 2
for i in range((lineas / 2) - 1):

    clyde.left(90)
    clyde.fd(canvas / float(lineas))
    clyde.left(90)
    clyde.fd(canvas / float(lineas))
    clyde.left(180)

    drawLine(b)
    b += 2
```